# How to read a string variable and compare it with string constant in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I need to read a string variable and to check if it's equal to string 'qwe'.
I try this code:

```
read VAR1
if ["$VAR1" == "rwx"]; then
    current=$current+1
fi
```

but terminal says

> [rwx : command not found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[` is a *command*, not just syntax. Commands need to be separated from their arguments with whitespace:

```sh
if [ "$VAR1" = "rwx" ]; then ...
#   ^               ^
```

See `help if` at an interactive prompt:

```
$ help if
if: if COMMANDS; then COMMANDS; [ elif COMMANDS; then COMMANDS; ]... [ else COMMANDS; ] fi
    Execute commands based on conditional.

    The `if COMMANDS' list is executed.  If its exit status is zero, then the
    `then COMMANDS' list is executed...
```

There's nothing in there about `[...]`, what comes after `if` is a **command list**, and the **exit status** determines the "success" of the conditional.

Comment: Adding to this, like any other UNIX command, you can look it up with `man [`, which on my machine shows that it is an alias of the `test` command

Comment: Right. I recommend this sequence: `help [` then `help test` then `help [[` in bash.

Comment: Going to the man page _first_ may not give you the best information: for example `test` is a shell builtin but also an external command (historical reasons). If `type $command` shows "$command is a shell builtin", read the `help` information (or the bash man page) before reaching for `man`.